# Deleting objects based on area calculation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a image with small objects. I have calculated their areas using

```
area=regionprops(CC,'Area');
```

CC is the connected components returned by

```
CC=bwconncomp(BW);
```

Now i need to remove objects with area less than 15 (set them to zero in the original image BW).

I know i can do this with a more simpler ways other than that from `regionprops`, but I need to do this from the output of `regionprops`, because I will extract other properties that is supported by `regionprops` and filter again the image according to these extracted features in a similar way. Can anyone help me with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the two commands you show,

```
CC=bwconncomp(BW);
area=regionprops(CC,'Area');
```

`area` is a struct array where `area(ii).Area` is the area for object `ii`. This corresponds to the connected component given by `CC.PixelIdxList{ii}`.

You can find the indices with a small area by

```
I = find([area.Area] < 15);
```

Then,

```
CC.PixelIdxList{I}
```

gives a comma-separated list of vectors with pixel indices. You can join these vectors into a single vector using `cat`:

```
pixels = cat(1,CC.PixelIdxList{I});
```

Now all that is left is setting those pixels to 0 in the input image:

```
BW(pixels) = 0;
```

Comment: Excellent explanation ! Thank you very much !!